# Regex to validate only 0 value. Single 0 value to be validated

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a regx problem. I already have a regx like this `[0-9]*([.][0-9]{2})`. This is an amont format validation. Now with this validation I want to include that no 0 amount should be provided. Like 10 is valid but 0 should be invalid.

Example of some valid values

```
10.00
10
1
```

Invalid

```
0
```

Would be appropriated if you provide some answer or let me know how to to it.

Comment: It looks like you want your data to not start with `0`...

Answer (score 3):

You can change your regular expression as follows:

```
[1-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{2})*
```

This will require at least one digit comprised between 1 and 9 before any other digit, and the optional trailing decimal value.

**Example**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9][0-9]*([.][0-9]{2})*");
String[] test = {"10.00", "10", "1", "0", "00.0"};
for (String s: test) {
    System.out.printf("%s is matched? %b%n", s, p.matcher(s).find());
}
```

**Output**

```
10.00 is matched? true
10 is matched? true
1 is matched? true
0 is matched? false
00.0 is matched? false
```